# Can i initialize child class in parent class

Tags: php, class, oop

I have a parent class and child class:

```
class Parent {
    function a() {
        $child = new child();
        $child->a1();
    }
}

class Child extends Parent{
    function a1() {

    }
}
```

How can I create object of child class in parent class. And child class is inheriting from same parent class where im trying to initialize child class.

Is this correct??

Comment: it's bad practice in OOP. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific/clear (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot name your class `Parent` this will cause your script to fail due to the following error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use 'Parent' as class name as it is reserved in
>   /var/www/html/class.php on line 2

That's due to the following:

> Three special keywords `self`, `parent` and `static` are used to access
>   properties or methods from inside the class definition.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

So as we renamed the class `Parent` to `Folk`, everything works.

```
<?PHP
error_reporting(E_ALL);
class Folk {
    function a() {
        $child = new Child();
        $child->a1();
    }
}

class Child extends Folk{
    function a1() {
        echo("hi");
    }
}



$folk = new Folk();
$folk->a();

?>
```

this outputs: `hi`

So to answer your question: **Yes**, you can create a child object in the parent class. Regardless of this being a good practice or not.